# how to enable and disable the service in android?

Tags: android, android-service

My application sends sms when the device get restarted.I send the current location of the device through SMS in back ground services.I want to provide choice to the user to enable and disable the background application.How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use shared pref preserver enable and disable states.

Register/de-register the boot-receiver (A broadcast receiver which listens for boot complete event) when enabled/disabled or read shared pref value in boot receiver and send/do nothing accordingly

Comment: so i've to store the flag value in shared pref.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two easy ways to go about this:

1) Set a flag that your receiver can check to ignore or accept broadcasts, and don't worry about enabling/disabling it at all.

2) Create the BroadcastReceiver programmatically (can just be an inner class), and register & unregister it as you need at given parts of your application.

In general I've found that defining my BroadcastReceivers in code instead of XML has provided a lot more flexibility and is generally easier for me to manage.

Regards
   -Sathya

Answer (score 1):

put an if in the service if enable do the service if disable don't...
put a button in your app that enables and disables the service you can use
shared preferences to remember user choice with Boolean

Answer (score 0):

I think you should devolope service class. and start that only if user choose enable.

if user choose enable :(sample code for start service)
                      {

```
                   intent = new Intent(TrackActivity.this, TrackService.class);
                intent.putExtra("IN_TRACKID", currentTrackId);
               intent.putExtra("IN_TRACK_TYPE",IN_TRACK_TYPE);
               startService(intent); 

                   }
```

Comment: please up vote answer if you find it correct or if not reply me.

Comment: I used shared pref value in boot receiver.thanks for your answer.